# issue in url rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i am trying to force non-www to www and its working as aspected:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

now if i visit `www.example.com/registration` it works great.. but when i am accessing the same url from an link it works but adds index.php?/ in the url like this:

```
www.example.com/index.php?/registration
```

i am new to .htaccess programming.. i can understand i need ot modify the below lines.. but i dont know how to modify in such a way so that i does not add `index.php?/` in the url...

```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

any help or suggestion would be great help.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```